# Need help in JavaScript Time and Date Function

Tags: javascript

If I use this it shows the full time like Sun Oct 18 2015 07:05:16 GMT-0700 (PDT).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var date = new Date();
        document.write(date);
</script>
```

But I want to only show the Day, Hour and Minute. How can I that?

Comment: `date.` **1.** `getDate()/getDay()` **2.** `getHours()` **3.** `getMinutes()`

Comment: Just look it up in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods).

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var monthname = months[date.getMonth()];
</script>
```

As @Tushar suggested.

Comment: Thanks but if i wanted to show the moth name what should I do?

Comment: @SamiulHaqueSohan Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.toDateString()
```

returns just the date. Or you can get date, month and year separately as suggested by @Tushar.

See [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to learn more about `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across anything that is direct in javascript maybe php but you can try this might be lengthy.

```
function time(d) {
    var k = new Array(7);
    k[0]=  "Sunday";
    k[1] = "Monday";
    k[2] = "Tuesday";
    k[3] = "Wednesday";
    k[4] = "Thursday";
    k[5] = "Friday";
    k[6] = "Saturday";

    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
    return(n+', '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes());
}
```

And then call it using.

```
time( new Date());
```

Hope that helps.